# COM+ Application Identity is not set

Tags: c#, windows, com+

I see a strange issue(Most likely my code is not complete), can some one take a look and help me out why following code runs fine but no changes are happening. Whn I go and take a look at identity tab, nothing has changed. OS is windows 2008 server r2

```
COMAdminCatalog cc = new COMAdminCatalog);
COMAdminCatalogCollection ccc = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)cc.GetCollection("Applications");
ccc.Populate();
foreach(COMAdminCatalogObject cap in ccc){
  if(cap.Name.ToString() == config.Application){
     //cap.set_value("Authentication",COMAdminAuthenticationLevelOptions.COMAdminAuthenticationConnect)//I have changed all options here but no effect
 cap.set_Value("Identity", config.user);
 cap.set_Value("Password", config.password);
 ccc.SaveChanges();//breakpoint here
  }
}
```

It turned out that ccc.SaveChanges() returns an error code =1 does any one know what it means?
MS documentation says error codes returned are in hex values such as 0x800401 etc(just made up)

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself (learn something new every day!) and this is my results, hopefully we can figure out your problem:

I created a new COM+ server Application and copied your code (with minor changes so it finds my app, because I don't know what `config` is in your example :)

From debugging up to `ccc.SaveChanges()` - this line should throw exceptions if something went wrong. In my case, I got an `UnauthorizedAccessException` - I fixed that by running my code in Visual Studio **as administrator**

Once I did that, `ccc.SaveChanges()` worked - I went to my Identity tab and it updated the user and password correctly (if you enter a wrong username or password in the code, it also throws an exception I believe).

The return type you are getting, the `1`, isn't an error code I believe. Because that's what mine returns and it is working fine.

You could try surrounding your `ccc.SaveChanges()` in a `try` `catch` and see if any exceptions are thrown.

I hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for taking the time to look into this.
Now this is even more baffling for me. Just to let you know I am using this code as an administrator on all machines where I have tested it. Something really STUPID I think I am missing..
I have tested this code on 3 different machines,
1:WinXP SP2
2:Win 7 SP1
3:Win2008 Server r2
It runs fine on all three machines, no error, no exception but change does not happen...
Could you be kind enough to let me know what .net framework version you tried this on where it worked? or if possible to send me your test application code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all THANK YOU ryrich for taking time to help me out. What it turned out to be the reason for which my changes were not shown is as dumb as it possibly can be. It is consistent on 3 machines where I tested it. Here is what I noticed.
Every time I run the code above, it did work as there were no errors, but I could not see the changes in Component Services Console, the messed up part is that I HAD to close the Component Services console completely, then restart it and only then I could see the changes.
This behavior was consistent on all three systems where I tested it.
1: WinXP sp3
2: Win 7 SP1
3: Win 2008 Server R2

I am explaining this so just in case some one else might see this STUPID behavior...

Comment: Weird! I'm glad you got it figured out. I noticed this too; if I had my Identity tab opened and ran my code, it didn't update. Another thing you can do for it to update is go to the Action menu in the Component Services Console and click Refresh. I haven't found a good way to do this in code unfortunately :( (there's a `cc.RefreshComponents` method but that didn't seem to work well)